# sql inner join - multicolumn

Tags: sql, join

can anyone help me with this sql query?

I have the following query:

```
select rps.res, rps.tar, rps.uni, rps.val
from TABLEX rps 
where rps.res = '1' 
   or rps.res = '2' 
   or rps.res = '3' 
order by rps.tar, rps.res asc
```

The Output looks like:

```
res | tar | uni | val
1   | A   | B   | 10
2   | A   | B   | 15
3   | A   | B   | 20
```

The output I would like to have is:

```
tar | uni | val1 | val2 | val3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your DBMS?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly apply `Conditional Aggregation` :

```
select tar, uni,
       max(case when tar = 1 then val end) as val1,
       max(case when tar = 2 then val end) as val2,
       max(case when tar = 3 then val end) as val3
  from tab
 group by tar, uni;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pivot using conditional aggregation and use `row_number()` for the numbering:

```
select tar, uni,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then val end) as val_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then val end) as val_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then val end) as val_3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by tar, uni order by val) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by tar, uni;
```